# Print between to points in a txt file

Tags: python, scripting

So Im wanting to write a script that parses through a file prints a specific section between two points. I wanted to do something like this:

```
+SECTION1
stufff
stufffff
more stufff
--
```

And I wanted to print everything from +SECTION1 to --. I also plan on having section 2, 3 and so on. Is there an easy way to accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
printing = False # Don't print until you've found a header
for line in f:
    if line == "--": # Once footer is found stop printing
        print line
        printing = False
    if printing: # Currently in between header and footer
        print line
    if line == "+SECTION1\n": # Once header is found start printing
        print line
        printing = True
```

To print as many sections as you want, you can place this block of code in a for loop:

```
for section in ("+SECTION1\n", "+SECTION2\n", "+SECTION3\n"):
    printing = False
    for line in f:
        if line == "--":
            print line
            printing = False
        if printing:
            print line
        if line == section:
            print line
            printing = True
```

As normal, I recommend placing this within a context manager:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would add this function somewhere in your script:

```
import re
def parse_section(start, stop, inputfile):
    startpattern = re.compile(start)
    stoppattern = re.compile(stop)
    print_content = False

    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()

            if startpattern.match(line):
                print_content = True
                continue
            if stoppattern.match(line):
                print_content = False
                continue

            if print_content:
                print line
```

And then use this command to get content from **+SECTION1** until **--**

- `parse_section('^\+SECTION1$', '^--$', 'input.txt')`
- and for **+SECTION2**, you can do: `parse_section('^\+SECTION2$', '^--$', 'input.txt')`
- and so on :)

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do this could be

for a file object f you could use

```
    f = open('workfile', 'r')
    for line in f:
        if line == '--':
            print "next section"
        else:
            print "the same section`
```